# App Engine creates new Version whenever I deploy Node app

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have hosted Node app to App Engine. Whenever I make some changes in existing code or add some new files and deploy it to App Engine using `gcloud app deploy`, it creates a new `Version` on App Engine even if I am not changing the configuration in my `app.yaml` file.

Below is my app.yaml file:

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs12
```

Is it possible to stop creating `Versions` every time after deployment?

Comment: In addition to GAEfan answer I would add that It's generally recommendable to check the gcloud CLI [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) when looking for these things.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--version=your_version_id` tag to your `gcloud app deploy` command.  Also consider the `--no-promote` and/or `--no-stop-previous-version` commands to keep the new version from becoming the active default.